# Specifying a nested variable correctly in Ansible

Tags: arrays, variables, hash, ansible

I need to pull some values out of a nested dictionary in ansible and I can't seem to do it.
Either I'm defining it badly or specifying it badly. And the ansible error messages are of course little help.

I have a vars file loaded that has the data structured like this:
For each site, I specify the vcenter and the domain controller

```
datacenters:
  - datacenter: Site1
    vars:
      vcenter_instance: vcenter1
      ADC: DC1
  - datacenter: Site2
    vars:
      vcenter_instance: vcenter2
      ADC: DC2
  - datacenter: Site3
    vars:
      vcenter_instance: vcenter1
      ADC: DC3
  - datacenter: TEST
    vars:
      vcenter_instance: vcentertest
      ADC: DC1
```

I added a debug task to see what the data looks like to Ansible. I gives me this:

```
        
        {
            "datacenter": "TEST",
            "vars": {
                "ADC": "DC1",
                "vcenter_instance": "vcentertest"
            }
        }
```

I set the datacenter value elsewhere and then try to pull in the needed data from the array

```
    - name: auto populate some variables based on which datacenter is selected
      set_fact:
        vcenter_hostname: "{{ datacenters[datacenter].vcenter_instance }}"
        ADController: "{{ datacenters[datacenter].ADC }}"
        Library: "'{{ datacenter  + '-' + 'Repository' }}"
```

I get the error
`"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'TEST'. 'list object' has no attribute 'TEST'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/runner/project/create_vm.yml': line 32, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: auto populate some variables based on which datacenter is selected\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the list to a dictionary

```yaml
  datacenters_dict: "{{ datacenters|
                        items2dict(key_name='datacenter',
                                   value_name='vars') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  datacenters_dict:
    Site1: {ADC: DC1, vcenter_instance: vcenter1}
    Site2: {ADC: DC2, vcenter_instance: vcenter2}
    Site3: {ADC: DC3, vcenter_instance: vcenter1}
    TEST: {ADC: DC1, vcenter_instance: vcentertest}
```

Then, use the dictionary and declare the variables

```yaml
  vcenter_hostname: "{{ datacenters_dict[datacenter].vcenter_instance }}"
  ADController: "{{ datacenters_dict[datacenter].ADC }}"
  Library: "{{ datacenter }}-Repository"
```

For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          datacenter: {{ datacenter }}
          vcenter_hostname: {{ vcenter_hostname }}
          ADController: {{ ADController }}
          Library: {{ Library }}
      vars:
        datacenter: Site3
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    datacenter: Site3
    vcenter_hostname: vcenter1
    ADController: DC3
    Library: Site3-Repository
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    datacenters:
      - datacenter: Site1
        vars: {ADC: DC1, vcenter_instance: vcenter1}
      - datacenter: Site2
        vars: {ADC: DC2, vcenter_instance: vcenter2}
      - datacenter: Site3
        vars: {ADC: DC3, vcenter_instance: vcenter1}
      - datacenter: TEST
        vars: {ADC: DC1, vcenter_instance: vcentertest}

    datacenters_dict: "{{ datacenters|
                          items2dict(key_name='datacenter',
                                     value_name='vars') }}"
    vcenter_hostname: "{{ datacenters_dict[datacenter].vcenter_instance }}"
    ADController: "{{ datacenters_dict[datacenter].ADC }}"
    Library: "{{ datacenter }}-Repository"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: datacenters_dict|to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: |
          datacenter: {{ datacenter }}
          vcenter_hostname: {{ vcenter_hostname }}
          ADController: {{ ADController }}
          Library: {{ Library }}
      vars:
        datacenter: Site3
```